# How do I realize port based VLAN

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm getting difficulties realizing a port based VLAN,Say we have VLAN10 (having three end stations) and  say VLAN10 is configured to one port(port1) on some Switch(s1).

Now how these three end stations can be connected to port1, physically we required three different links to connect to three different ports but here we connecting or saying three end stations are connecting to port1.

Comment: Do not cross post. You asked this exact same question on SO, where I answered it and told you to read up on these topics **before** asking any more questions. Go read up on vLANs and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Why then not just configure 3 ports on your switch that all use VLAN10?

Your other option is to use a dumb switch and attach it to port1. You can then attach your other devices to this switch.

Do mind that no other vlan must be attached to this switch then (no trunking). Otherwise a  problem that will arise is when your frames are at max length, the dumb switch will think the frame is too large (doesn't recognize VLAN tag) and damaged and drop it.

Comment: there is any docs where i visualize how Port based LAN's are works

Comment: I think CCNA module 3 covers this quite well

Comment: Given that this is an access port and not a trunk port, and given that there is no separate voice VLAN mentioned, would the unmanaged switch that you are proposing ever encounter a tagged packet? I think not.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about that :(